# lxml xpath expression for selecting all text under a given child node including his children

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, children

Provided I have a XML as follows:

```
<node1>
    <text title='book'>
       <div chapter='0'>
          <div id='theNode'>
              <p xml:id="40">
               A House that has:
                   <p xml:id="45">- a window;</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
               its a beuatiful house
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </text>
</node1>
```

I would like to locate text title and get all the text from the first p tag appearing inside the text title book node

so far I know:

```
from lxml import etree
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(XML_content,parser=parser)
text = XML_tree.xpath('//text[@title="book"]/div/div/p/text()')
```

gets: "A house that has is a beautiful house"

But I would like also all the text of all the possible children and great children of the first

appearing under

basically; look for  then look for the first

and give me all the text under that p tag whatever the nesting.

pseudo code:

```
text = XML_tree.xpath('//text[@title="book"]/... any number of nodes.../p/ ....all text under p')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using either [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string) or [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-normalize-space)...

```py
from lxml import etree

XML_content = """
<node1>
    <text title='book'>
       <div chapter='0'>
          <div id='theNode'>
              <p xml:id="x40">
               A House that has:
                   <p xml:id="x45">- a window;</p>
                   <p xml:id="x46">- a door</p>
                   <p xml:id="x47">- a door</p>
               its a beuatiful house
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </text>
</node1>
"""

XML_tree = etree.fromstring(XML_content)
text = XML_tree.xpath('string(//text[@title="book"]/div/div/p)')
# text = XML_tree.xpath('normalize-space(//text[@title="book"]/div/div/p)')
print(text)
```

Output using `string()`...

```
               A House that has:
                   - a window;
                   - a door
                   - a door
               its a beuatiful house
```

Output using `normalize-space()`...

```
A House that has: - a window; - a door - a door its a beuatiful house
```

Comment: Quick question, if you don't mind: I notice you inserted an `x` before the attribute value of each `xml:id`; why was that necessary?

Comment: @JackFleeting - a value starting with a number is not a valid xml id. I had to add the “x” and change the last id from x46 to x47 to be able to get lxml to parse the xml.

Comment: Got it; thanks! FYI, I managed to get the same results with the exact version of OP's example (including the duplicated id) using lxml.html...

Comment: @JackFleeting yeah lxml.html is pretty good at dealing with xml-like (not well-formed) data. It’s a lot easier when the original question has code you can use reproduce the output without any modifications.

Comment: @DanielHaley   my XML id comes like this: <change xml:id="4f80be14e21....". Just saying.

Comment: @DanielHaley you are right, I am getting an error like: xml:id : attribute value 6bb011667...etc is not an NCName. The question is then how to parse a XML like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(XML_content)
text = [el.strip() for el in XML_tree.xpath('//text()[ancestor::text[@title="book"]][normalize-space()]')]
print(" ".join(text))
print("\n".join(text))
```

Output :

```
A House that has: - a window; - a door - a door its a beuatiful house
A House that has:
- a window;
- a door
- a door
its a beuatiful house
```