# Parsing an XML file with invalid xml:id values (starting with a number)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

Provided I have a XML as follows:
Notice that the attributes xml:id are strings STARTING BY NUMBERS

```
<node1>
    <text xml:id='7865ft6zh67'>
       <div chapter='0'>
          <div id='theNode'>
              <p xml:id="40">
               A House that has:
                   <p xml:id="45">- a window;</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
               its a beuatiful house
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </text>
</node1>
```

I would like to locate text title and get all the text from the first p tag appearing inside the text title book node

A first approach can be done using the answers here:
[lxml xpath expression for selecting all text under a given child node including his children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472162/lxml-xpath-expression-for-selecting-all-text-under-a-given-child-node-including) (my own question)

But in this new XML (compared to the mentioned question) the xml:id s start with a number and as pointed in one of that answers  the following error occurs when using the code:

```
 xml:id : attribute value 7865ft6zh67 is not an NCName, line 3, column 31
```

How can I still parse the XML with that "XML non compliance xml:id"?

So far the only solution that I can think of is passing the xml to string, and adding a letter at the beginning of every of those xml:ids" like:

```
newXML = '...hange><change xml:id="6f58f74883d55b...'
newXML_repared = newXML.replace('xml:id="','xml:id="XXid')
newXML_repared

from lxml import etree
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(newXML_repared,parser=parser)
```

but when doing so I get:

```
 ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

Any suggestion?

note: I noticed that the string itself starts by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teiCorpus subtype="simple"  ...etc
```

In the lxml tutorial is possible to read:
This requires, however, that unicode strings do not specify a conflicting encoding themselves and thus lie about their real encoding:
(https://lxml.de/parsing.html)

But I still dont know how to solve the problem then

Thanks.

Comment: Preferably not using BS because the whole rest of the team uses lxml, nobody in the team uses BS and the idea is sticking to one library.

Comment: And apparently "BeautifulSoup, by itself, does not support XPath expressions.". we need xpath because the xmls we work with are extremely complicated and nested. But thanks for your answer

Comment: With `bs4` you can use CSS selectors + bs4's own api.

Comment: Where does the bad XML come from? This should be fixed by whatever/whoever created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is found in the link to the docs you provided (https://lxml.de/parsing.html).

Specifically the "recover" option listed in [parser options](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options).

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

XML_content = """
<node1>
    <text xml:id='7865ft6zh67' title="book">
       <div chapter='0'>
          <div id='theNode'>
              <p xml:id="40">
               A House that has:
                   <p xml:id="45">- a window;</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
                   <p xml:id="46">- a door</p>
               its a beuatiful house
               </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </text>
</node1>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

XML_tree = etree.fromstring(XML_content, parser=parser)
text = XML_tree.xpath('normalize-space(//text[@title="book"]/div/div/p)')
# text = XML_tree.xpath('string(//text[@title="book"]/div/div/p)')
print(text)
```

Note: I added `title="book"` so the XPath from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474543/317052) in your related question still worked.

Comment: lxml's `recover=True` can be useful for [cleaning up "bad" XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085), but readers should be reminded that problems such as starting ids with digits violate the rules of well-formedness, and so really should be fixed at the source.  Otherwise, every consumer of the "XML" has to suffer these problems, defeating the benefits of using standards.